# Yii2- Hide admin settings based on user role

Tags: yii2, treeview, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I have a tree in which I am displaying nodes and their child nodes. I want to hide the non `admin` options to a user whose not an admin. By default, the `isAdmin` is `true`. For checking user roles I have done the following.

```
<?=
TreeView::widget([
    'query' => \common\models\MdcNode::find()->addOrderBy('root, lft'),
    'headingOptions' => ['label' => 'Root'],
    'rootOptions' => ['label'=>'<span class="text-primary">Root</span>'],
    'topRootAsHeading' => true, // this will override the headingOptions
    'fontAwesome' => true,
    'isAdmin' => function(){
          if (Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == 1)
          {
              return true;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
    },
    'iconEditSettings'=> [
        'show' => 'list',
        'listData' => [
            'building' => 'Building',
            'folder' => 'Floor',
            'user' => 'Customer'
        ]
    ],
    'softDelete' => true,
    'cacheSettings' => ['enableCache' => true]
]);
?>
```

Now when I run my code. I am getting below error when I click on the node

```
Operation Disallowed
Invalid request signature detected during tree data manage action! Please refresh the page and retry.
OLD HASH:
785a3cf9cbb1a90e862b718ed8ae3289944280448ae801de49d686aa5f70e951common\models\MdcNodehidebtn-default/mdc/backend/web/treemanager/node/save/mdc/backend/web/mdcnode/index@kvtree/views/_formw0-nodeselnodenodes<div class="kv-node-message">No valid nodes are available for display. Use toolbar buttons to add nodes.</div>111111{"id":"w0-nodeform"}{"1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":""}{"submit":"<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\"></i>","reset":"<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-repeat\"></i>"}a:0:{}[]list{"":"<em>Default</em> ( <span class=\"text-warning kv-node-icon kv-icon-parent\"><i class=\"fa fa-folder-close kv-node-closed\"></i></span> / <span class=\"text-warning kv-node-icon kv-icon-parent\"><i class=\"fa fa-folder-open kv-node-opened\"></i></span> / <span class=\"text-info kv-node-icon kv-icon-child\"><i class=\"fa fa-file\"></i></span>)","building":"<span class=\"fa fa-building\"></span> Building","folder":"<span class=\"fa fa-folder\"></span> Floor","user":"<span class=\"fa fa-user\"></span> Customer"}{"depth":"","glue":" &raquo; ","activeCss":"kv-crumb-active","untitled":"Untitled"}
NEW HASH:
e3037c327c2ddec080a38ce50002f825a214352f833f2acfe972c3d7d0a2b9abcommon\models\MdcNodehidebtn-default/mdc/backend/web/treemanager/node/save/mdc/backend/web/mdcnode/index@kvtree/views/_formw0-nodeselnodenodes<div class="kv-node-message">No valid nodes are available for display. Use toolbar buttons to add nodes.</div>11111{"id":"w0-nodeform"}{"1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":""}{"submit":"<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\"></i>","reset":"<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-repeat\"></i>"}a:0:{}[]list{"":"<em>Default</em> ( <span class=\"text-warning kv-node-icon kv-icon-parent\"><i class=\"fa fa-folder-close kv-node-closed\"></i></span> / <span class=\"text-warning kv-node-icon kv-icon-parent\"><i class=\"fa fa-folder-open kv-node-opened\"></i></span> / <span class=\"text-info kv-node-icon kv-icon-child\"><i class=\"fa fa-file\"></i></span>)","building":"<span class=\"fa fa-building\"></span> Building","folder":"<span class=\"fa fa-folder\"></span> Floor","user":"<span class=\"fa fa-user\"></span> Customer"}{"depth":"","glue":" &raquo; ","activeCss":"kv-crumb-active","untitled":"Untitled"}
```

**Update 1**

Below is my user model

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
}

/**
 * Finds user by username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
}

/**
 * Finds user by password reset token
 *
 * @param string $token password reset token
 * @return static|null
 */
public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
{
    if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
        return null;
    }

    return static::findOne([
        'password_reset_token' => $token,
        'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Finds out if password reset token is valid
 *
 * @param string $token password reset token
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
{
    if (empty($token)) {
        return false;
    }

    $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
    $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
    return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryKey();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param string $password password to validate
 * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}

/**
 * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
 *
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

/**
 * Generates "remember me" authentication key
 */
public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

/**
 * Generates new password reset token
 */
public function generatePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
}

/**
 * Removes password reset token
 */
public function removePasswordResetToken()
{
    $this->password_reset_token = null;
}   

public static function toArrayList()
{
    return ArrayHelper::map(self::find()->where(['user_role'=>2,'status'=>10])->all(),'id','username');
}
}
```

**User Table Structure**

[image]

**RBAC Model**

```
class Rbac extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'rbac';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['controller', 'action'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['roles'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'controller' => 'Controller',
        'action' => 'Action',
        'roles' => 'Roles',
    ];
}

public static function allowAccess($c,$a){
    $sql= /** @lang text */
        "select count(*) as total from rbac where (controller='$c' and action='$a') and (roles = '' OR roles IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(". Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role . ",roles)<>0)";

    $rbac = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);

    $r = $rbac->queryOne();
    return $r['total'] > 0;
}
}
```

Comment: How do you check if it is ever user isGuest or Loged in? You Trying to get access to user identity interface but you does not show how you prevent access to this action for guests.

Comment: Usually you check if the user is Guest like this: `Yii::$app->user->isGuest()` which will return `true OR false` and if you have setup `RBAC` module correct you will be able to check as well, lets say, if user can have access to this particular view like this: `Yii::$app->user->can('accessFile')`

Comment: Also can you post you `User` model?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Let me share my model

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco check my update 1

Comment: Your `user` model does not implement `user interface` which you trying to access using `Yii`. it should be `class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface`

Comment: After that you should have access to `Yii::$app->user->identity->role` if your user table column has role name set like `role`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco my bad. I have posted the correct one, please check

Comment: Again how do you check if the user is not a Guest? and post you user table structure

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I am able to check `Guest` or any other user role via `user_role` that is in my user table. I have shared the structure as well

Comment: Can you post you `RBAC`console  model

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I have posted it please see

Comment: Have you made this controller by yourself?

Comment: Can you post what `user` CAN do? or `admin` CAN do? How you check user permissions?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I am using `Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role` to check

Comment: Yes, but how you check if the user can access? like `Yii::$app->user->can('edit-post')`?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I haven't checked that all I am using is to check the role and it's working perfect.

Comment: Then your RBAC does not make sense. Have you trying to read the official documentation for RBAC? It will be a lot easier for you in the future m.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco yes you are right but It's working in another way round so for now I don't have to use RBAC full functionality?

Comment: did you by any chance updated your extension by running `composer update` ? and you should be using RBAC and simply call `Yii::$app->user->can($route)` for the `isAdmin` property, never go out of the scope of a framework and follow the conventional approach to implement your features so that you dont run into such problems

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no I haven't updated the extension. Already using `Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role` is working for other modules as well.

Comment: well that is a separate discussion and i wont go towards that part, you get the above error with the default code too? or when you add a specific option?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes with the default code I am getting this error on click of node

Comment: can you update to the latest version and then clear the `assets` directory and then try once again